# Getting "Invalid Scopes: publish_actions" error when requesting for publish_actions permission of Facebook on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-permissions

I'm simply trying to get the user permission after the user has successfully logged in to share posts on Facebook using the code:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this,
                Arrays.asList("publish_actions"))
```

And getting the following error:
[image]

I have even tried visiting the link mentioned, but there was no help about the permission publish_actions.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24